# SSL certificate default for domain in Plesk > 11

Tags: ssl, plesk

I've several `$DOMAIN` in different plesk servers (all above v.11).
I've a script that renew the certificates for some of them.

I need to know how can I set, via CLI, the updated certificate to be the default one for `$DOMAIN`.
There is a `-default` flag for `/usr/local/psa/bin/certificate` utility, but is not valid for domain, rather for admin pool (so the plesk server itself).

So far, I go ahead and from the web interface I set the newly created certificate for each domain.
This is the script I use (after having updated the SSL certificates via certbot script):

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/certificate \
    -c "${DOMAIN}-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" \
    -domain ${DOMAIN}  \
    -csr-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}/${DOMAIN}.csr \
    -cacert-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}.ca \
    -cert-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}.crt \
    -key-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}.key
```

I would expect that  the certificate named "`${DOMAIN}-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`" is the default one for `$DOMAIN`.
How can I accomplish that via script, and not via web interface?

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my own question.
The problem is that I was creating a new certificate, while there's no need to create one, rather update the existing certificate.

So, the script should be updated as follow:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/certificate \
    -u "$CERTIFICATE_NAME_IN_USE" \
    -domain ${DOMAIN}  \
    -csr-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}/${DOMAIN}.csr \
    -cacert-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}.ca \
    -cert-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}.crt \
    -key-file /etc/ssl/certbot/${DOMAIN}.key
```

The variable of $CERTIFICATE_NAME_IN_USE can be easily get with the following command:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/certificate -l -domain ${DOMAIN} | grep ${DOMAIN} | awk '$6 != "0" {print $5}'
```

Hope this helps to someone else.